# recreate conditioned fragments without button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my Application there are four ButtonNavigationView tabs with fragments, i want 2 of them to refresh every time i click on them and the other 2 to not refresh every time i click on them , how can i get that?

## Home Activity

```
final Fragment factorsFragment = new FactorsFragment();
    final Fragment newFactorFragment = new NewFactorFragment();
    final Fragment productsFragment = new ProductsFragment();
    final Fragment checkList = new CheckList();

    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment active = newFactorFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, productsFragment, "4").hide(productsFragment).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, factorsFragment, "3").hide(factorsFragment).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, checkList, "2").hide(checkList).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, newFactorFragment, "1").commit();

        SQLiteStudioService.instance().start(this);



    }
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(factorsFragment).commit();
                    active = factorsFragment;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(newFactorFragment).commit();
                    active = newFactorFragment;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(productsFragment).commit();
                    active = productsFragment;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_checklist:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(checkList).commit();
                    active = checkList;
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    };
```

i want factorFragment and productFragment to refresh without adding a swiperefreshlayout or custom refresh button

my problem is all of my fragments don't refresh on tab change, because i am just making them show and hide , but i want 2 of them to refresh.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call all the functions of your factorFragment and productFragment in onResume of the respective fragments. Changes will reflect as you are calling the methods again in onResume.

Fragment has offset. So if you are loading one fragment in activity the next few(depends on what you set or the default offset) fragments also get initialized. That's why it will be wise to recall your functions in onResume.